# How to integrate image preload code into my current code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, preload

When my cursor is on link that changes background image, that image dissapears and reappears. I know that heppens because I have to preload images if I'm using them in js. So I found [this](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/image/preload.html) and I want to use the first option. But I don't know how to integrate it into my code. My code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MqBxN/1/). Would you please help to do that?

**CSS**

```
body
    {
        background-image:url(Slike/Ozadja/Osnova.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        background-attachment:local;
        background-color: #FFFAF0;
        background-size:794px;
    }

    #layoutWidth div
    {
        width:628px;
        margin:auto;
        display:table;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    div .header
    {
        height:85px;
        text-align:center;
        display:table-row;
    }

    div .menu 
    {
    height:173px;
    display:table-row;
    }

    #ddm
    {   margin-top: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 30}

    #ddm li
    {   margin-left:12px;
        margin-top:10px;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        font: bold 100% arial}

    #ddm li a
    {   display: block;
        margin: 0 6px 0 0;
        padding: 4px 4px;
        width: 130px;
        background: transperent;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none}

    #ddm li a:hover
    {   background: transparent;
        color: #C0C0C0;
        }

    #ddm div
    {   position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        margin-top:10px;
        padding: 0;
        background: transparent;
        }


        #ddm  div a
        {   position: static;
            display: block;
            margin-left: -16px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            width: 150px;
            white-space: normal;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            background: transperent;
            color: #000;
            font: bold 11px arial;
            }

        #ddm div a:hover
        {   background: transparent;
            color: #696969}

    div .body
    {   
        height:650px;
        text-align: left;
        display:table-row;
    }

    div .footer 
    {   

        display:table-row;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Drop-Down Menu</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html;charset=UTF-16">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stil.css">

<!-- dd menu -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var timeout         = 500;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;
var myImage         = {};
myImage.m1 = 'Prvi_predal.png';
myImage.m2 = 'Drugi_predal.png';
myImage.m3 = 'Tretji_predal.png';
myImage.m4 = 'Cetrti_predal.png';

function mopen(id)
{   
    mcancelclosetime();

    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(Slike/Ozadja/'+myImage[id]+')';
}


function mclose()
{
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(Slike/Ozadja/Osnova.png)'
}

function mclosetime()
{
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}

function mcancelclosetime()
{
    if(closetimer)
    {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}

document.onclick = mclose; 

// -->

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="layoutWidth">
<div class="header">
<a href="Domov.html">
<img src="Slike/Logo/Logo.png" alt="Mankajoč logotip" width="279" height="80"></a>
</div>



<div class="menu">
<ul id="ddm">
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Obdelava lesa</a>
        <div id="m1" class="prvi" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">Izdelki iz iverala</a>
        <a href="#">Izdelki iz masive</a>
        <a href="#">Obnova pohištva</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m2')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Talne obloge</a>
        <div id="m2" class="drugi" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">Laminat</a>
        <a href="#">Parket</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m3')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Ostale storitve</a>
        <div id="m3" class="tretji" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">Uporaba mavčnih plošč</a>
        <a href="#">Lažja zidarska dela</a>
        <a href="#">Fotografiranje dogodkov</a>
        <a href="#">Video zajem dogodkov</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m4')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Informacije</a>
        <div id="m4" class="cetrti" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">O podjetju</a>
        <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
        <a href="#">Kje se nahajamo</a>
        <a href="#">Galerija</a>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

<div class="body">
</div>

<div class="footer">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough solution, which will force browser to load and cache all these images. So when you will change background image will be got from cache.

Add preload function in your code, just before this line: document.onclick = mclose;

```
function preload() {
    var src, image, images = [];
    for (src in myImage) {
        if (typeof myImage[src] == 'string') {
                image = new Image();
                image.src = myImage[img];
                images.push(image);
        }
    }    
}
preload();
```

[JsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/RU29a/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this still doesn't work. Backgrounds still disappear and reappear. This problem is also visible in jsFiddle code.

Comment: Hi, try this one: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RU29a/3/). It use class name switching instead of changing background image directly.

**UPDATE:**
Looks like anyway it blinks for first time.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but as you noticed, it still doesn't work as it should. But you know, I would never come up with this code you wrote alone.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I've also tried this approach [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/), but unfortunately have no success with it.

Comment: Thank you again and if you come across something that might help me feel free to comment:). Have a nice day.